# display part of description in href using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my code i have the following:

```
optionlist.AppendFormat("<li>
<a href=\"setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting={0}\">{1}</a>
</li>", DB.RSField(rs, "Name"), DB.RSField(rs, "Name"));
```

Name in the database has the following value: **en-US**

How can i miss the first 3 string characters and only display **US**

IF the locale shows up as fr-FR it doesnt make sense to show fr 2 times.

BUT i need to keep the value in the a href as fr-FR just need to show it as FR.

I could create a new field inteh DB and call it Description2 and then manually write down US and FR and DE for each country. This would be my quick workaround. Any ideas how id literally take away 3 string characters from the description?

Comment: Why not stick with RFC 3066? It's unambiguous and familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
optionlist.AppendFormat("<li>
<a href=\"setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting={0}\">{1}</a>
</li>", DB.RSField(rs, "Name").Substring(3), DB.RSField(rs, "Name").Substring(3));
```

Comment: the substring should just be on the last one {1} but yes this works thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use substring if the char length is always the same

```
String x = "en-US";
x.Substring(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just displaying the string, you can keep the second argument (`{1}`) as

```
DB.RSField(rs, "Name").Substring(DB.RSField(rs, "Name").IndexOf('-')+1, 2)
```

...and keep `{0}` the same as you need it for your `href`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] subStr = Name.Split("-");

optionlist.AppendFormat("<li>
<a href=\"setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting={0}\">{1}</a>
</li>", DB.RSField(rs, subStr[1]), DB.RSField(rs, subStr[1]));
```